# Java Applet failing to load, but browser shows <applet> tags

Tags: java, applet, jvm, loading, silent

I'm having a problem on a system I'm working on, where the users report that intermittently a Java applet silently fails to load. Note that most of the time it works, but fairly regularly someone will report this silent failure.

On investigation, I've found that:

- The `<applet>` tags are there in the browser, with all the required information.
- The browser won't let me right-click on the area it's allocated for the applet: nothing happens at all.
- I don't see the Java animation that you normally get when it's loading the JVM. No java console pops up either!

This has got me stumped - anyone got any bright ideas? What would cause the browser (Firefox in this case) to not instantiate the JVM? How can I debug this more efficiently?

Comment: Prepare a simple text page with nothing but the applet.  But don't put an applet element, use the deployment toolkit script to launch it.  Then validate the remaining (short) HTML.

Comment: Have you installed Java Tm Plugin Addon on mozilla?

Answer (score 0):

For Debuggin Applets , Follow Below Steps on

### Windows OS

#### Step 1

Go to Control Panel -> Java -> Advance Options ->

> Enable Debugging options

[image: Applet Debugging snap shot]

You may also find many options there... Check Security Level also....

#### Step 2

But you are saying that browser is not prompting you to run plugin, then it is because you may disable plugin forever.

> Check add on , if you have selected `"Never Activate"` option??

In Mozilla, Go to Tools -> Add ons

[image: mozilla addon for java]

If you are using different Operating System then [check here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/client-security.html).

I hope this helps....